# call method on touch sensor press mindstorms java

Tags: java, lego-mindstorms

I am dealing with a program that calls a method (or methods) on a touch sensor press with mindstorms lejos java. I need a reliable way to call the methods as I may be dealing with several presses in a second. Thank You! :D